# Calling a function and storing the value in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep wcm2_wcm2appwlx | awk '$0!~/grep/ && $2~/[0-9]/{print $2}'`
for I in 1 2 3 4 5
do
sts=$(check)
  if [$sts eq / true/]
  then
        echo $I
        slp
  else
        break              #Abandon the loop.
  fi
done
slp(){
echo "sleep is executing "
}
check(){
if ps -p $pid > /dev/null
then
   echo " Backup Script is running with $PID "
   return true
fi
}
```

Comment: O/p : sh -x test.sh
++ ps -ef
++ grep wcm2_wcm2appwlx
++ awk '$0!~/grep/ && $2~/[0-9]/{print $2}'
+ pid=39641
+ for I in 1 2 3 4 5
++ check
test.sh: line 5: check: command not found
+ sts=
+ '[' eq / 'true/]'
test.sh: line 7: [: missing `]'
+ break

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You're missing a '}' on the `check` function.  Is that a copy/paste error or is it missing in your code?

Comment: @David King Sorry that's a copy paste Mistake

Answer (score 2):

The `var=$()` syntax will store `stdout` from the code within the parens in the variable, not the exit value of the function/process.  The exit/return value will be stored in `$?`

You could be testing `sts` as a string for the content of the echo, or you could check `$?` against the expected return value.  In my bash I cannot return `true` only numeric values.

Also note that the spaces around `[` and `]` are not optional, you must include them.  So

```
sts=$(check)
if [[ "$sts" = *"is running"* ]]; then
    ...
```

note also I used `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` so I could use the wildcard match

You could also do

```
if check; then
    ...
```

if you have `check` return 0 or "success"

Comment: Thanks @Eric Renouf But i still get the following error 
`sh -x test.sh 
+ awk $0!~/grep/ && $2~/[0-9]/{print $2}
+ grep wcm2_wcm2appwlx
+ ps -ef
+ pid=
+ check
test.sh: 5: test.sh: check: not found
+ sts=
+ [[ == *is running* ]]
test.sh: 7: test.sh: [[: not found
+ break
`

Comment: @VinayThupili right, I was only addressing the question at hand and few other things.  Given your comment I'll add a couple more: you have to declare the functions before you use them so put those at the top, and if you're going to take my suggestion of using `[[` instead of `[` you have to use a shell like `bash`, not `sh`

Comment: @VinayThupili what exactly are you trying to do with this anyway?  It looks like you're looking for a process with a given name whose parent pid contains a digit, which will be all of them with that name, I don't think you can have a process without a parent pid containing a digit

Comment: As given in above example I have declared function called check and I want to give the output of function check to a variable called sts Ex: sts=$(check) . but after declaring the function also it's showing the error which i have described in the comment.. I'm just not getting the fault in the script. I've tried if check then ;... fi also where check returns 0. Even it didn't work